# iOS App Signer - Unable to Fix -- I was unable to automatically resolve your codesigning issue

Tags: ios, xcode, keychain, sign

When I start iOS App signer show this Alert [image: show this Alert]

and then I click `Yes`  after few minute show This Alert[image: this Alert]

I go into keychain and delete any personal certificates mentioning Mac Developer, iOS Developer, etc, and add my account add certificate again but not working

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand this Alert showing when I have a lot of key on my system, for this matter, I can't build a sign for my app, I just install this program another system it works, I think the basic problem ios appSigner have trouble and this program noting update!!

Answer (score 0):

FIXED SIGNING ISSUE!
(spent HOURS trying to fix this, and tried TONS of variations with only small changes to each variation)

Steps:

1. Open Keychain Access
2. Delete ALL certs in login and system (for keychains) and in Certificates and My Certificates under Category (left bottom)
3. Quit Xcode, Opened Xcode. Went to Xcode > Preferences > (made sure I was signed in), Highlighted the apple ID on the left, then highlighted the Team name on the bottom right, then clicked Manage Certificates. Clicked the + sign then iOS Development. I then noticed it added my cert in the keychain app which was running in the background.
4. Downloaded: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/AppleWWDRCAG3.cer (from https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/) Opened it and it suddenly changed my cert in Keychain from untrusted to "This Certifcate is valid".
5. Opened iOS App Signer then selected my input file, then selected the Signing Cert (which had one choice), selected my Provisioning Profile.
6. Clicked START and DONE!